# Why can't I import primereact styles to webpack 4 react boilerplate?

Tags: webpack-4, css-loader, webpack-style-loader, primereact

I am getting this error when I run the app:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
Unknown word (2:1)

  1 |
> 2 | var content = require("!!../../../../css-loader/index.js!./theme.css");
    | ^
  3 |
  4 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
  5 |

 @ ./node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css 2:14-136 21:1-42:3 22:19-141
 @ ./src/index.js
```

I have not modified any of the common, dev and prod webpacks. I've read the other 2 questions posted around this but none of the answers worked.
I'll post the webpack configurations for your convenience.

Common:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src", "index.js"),
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3042,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        overlay: true,
        open: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{ loader: "babel-loader" }]
            },
            {
                test: /.*\.(gif|png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "url-loader",
                        options: {
                            limit: 21000,
                            name: "images/[name]_[hash:7].[ext]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            // Vendor CSS loader
            // This is necessary to pack third party libraries like antd
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules'),
                use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'),
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
}
```

Dev:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const mapStyle = process.env.MAP_STYLE === 'true';

module.exports = merge (common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        port: 3042,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        overlay: true,
        open: true,
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: mapStyle ? "css-loader?sourceMap" : "css-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
        }),
    ],
});
```

Prod:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

const enableBundleAnalyzer = process.env.ENABLE_ANALYZER === 'true';

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
        },
        runtimeChunk: false,
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')], {
            root: process.cwd(),
            verbose: true,
            dry: false
        }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].[hash:8].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].[hash:8].css"
        }),
        new ManifestPlugin(),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: enableBundleAnalyzer === true ? 'static' : 'disabled',
            openAnalyzer: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

And here is where I import them:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import App from './components/App';
import store from './app/store';

import './assets/styles/style.sass';
import './assets/styles/style.css';
import './index.scss';

import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
import 'primeflex/primeflex.css';

import 'primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
import '/src/assets/styles/customTheme.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// Check if hot reloading is enable. If it is, changes won't reload the page.
// This is related to webpack-dev-server and works on development only.
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

One of the questions answered this by saying that i needed the url-loader but, as you can see, the boilerplate contains that aswell.

I hope I gave you enough information. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found my answer. I needed to exclude node_modules from the css loader rules from both the dev and prod configurations since the common configuration was handling that. The error was thrown because there were 2 conflicting css loaders.